# Syntax of one line IF condition in Python

Tags: python, ternary-operator

Can someone say why this doesn't work in Python? Is it simply invalid syntax or is there more to it?

```
arr[0] += 12 if am_or_pm == 'PM'
```

The error message:

```
  File "solution.py", line 13
    arr[0] += 12 if am_or_pm == 'PM'
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This works:

```
if am_or_pm == 'PM': arr[0] += 12
```

Comment: That's not valid syntax. Maybe you're thinking of [ternary conditional operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)? `arr[0] += 12 if am_or_pm == 'PM' else 0`

Comment: for better readability you may use `if` in a separate line, but the ternary conditional operator Ted suggested is fine as well.

Comment: Thanks guys, that helps. So I either need to specify an 'else' branch to make it a ternary operation or go with the classic if syntax. Thanks again!

Comment: @Andras Exactly. The reason is that the conditional expression is _an expression_. Leaving out the `else` would result in the "expression" having no defined value; e.g., what should `print('hi' if False)` sensibly do (if we refrain from using `None` everywhere automatically, which is a design choice)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is surely a kind of usage in Python that the `if` and `else` clause is in the same line. This is used when you need to assign a value to a variable under certain conditions. Like this

```
a = 1 if b == 1 else 2
```

This means if `b` is 1, `a` will be 1, else, `a` will be 2.
But `if` and `else` must **all** be written to form the valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

python doesn't have semicolon. So there is break line into the same line. python consider code into a same line that written in a line. so here a expression and a conditional statement in a same line that is not valid. python interpreter doesn't recognize what the code exactly mean. you can use separate line for this.

```
arr[0] += 12 
if am_or_pm == 'PM':
```